# I want use magento2 default contact form in my static block

Tags: magento2

Hi I am trying to use Default contact form in my static block or custom cms page. for that I am using this code. but not getting any result.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call your contact form block with template file in the cms pages.

Try below code :

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Can I use this in custom statick block

Comment: Yes you can use it

Comment: this is not working in custom static block

Comment: When I include this in custom Block- and open this , my page does not load

Comment: @sanjay okay have you switched the WYSIWYG editor and puted this code as an plain text ? also can you please check you have selected all store view option from store view dropdown ?

Comment: I disabled  WYSIWYG from backend , stille this issue is coming on

Comment: strange try to put in default blocks like footer and check if it is work or not .

Answer (score 3):

There are two mistakes:

1) use **Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm** instead of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.

2) Define your module in template **Magento_Contact::form.phtml**.

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your block class is Incorrect, because `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` is default block of Magento 2 and for contact us  you should write, `Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm`, like this

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use just below code

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: SH patel, can i used this code in my custom static block this is not working right now

Comment: Yes you can use it in custom static block.

Comment: But when I use this @ it's  does not showing any thing